# Powershell how to split string after or before ('/')

Tags: powershell

I have a usecase that I would like to split. Below is the output of a program in a txt file. I need the VALUE part alone to be written in another txt file to be read by another process.

**OUTPUT: "Id": "/Name/VALUE",**

I tried

```
$text.split('/')[1].split(' ')
```

but it resulted in giving me "Name"
On the whole, what am I doing is

```
$text = Get-Content C:\temp\file.txt
$text.split('/')[1].split(' ') | Out-File C:\temp\file1.txt
```

Comment: `$text` has 2 `/`.  The split has therefore 3 entries: 0, 1, and 2.  As you found out 1 is `Name`.  Why do you split again?

Comment: I can't split again as the out of split is capture in a file with Name only like
Name
Name

Comment: Please [format your code and sample input/output properly](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/22189/248777).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do it step by step and look at the results, you'll see that

```
PS C:\> 'OUTPUT: "Id": "/Name/VALUE",'.Split('/')
OUTPUT: "Id": "
Name
VALUE",
```

The first line is index 0, the second line (Name) is index 1, the third line (VALUE",) is index 2.

You could get the VALUE by:

```
$text.Split('/')[2].Replace('",', '')
```

To take the Value line and remove the quote and comma.

Comment: This worked like a charm. What exactly i was looking for. Thanks a ton

Answer (score 0):

Method 1 with array of delimiter:

```
$content.split(@('"', '/'))[5]
```

Method 2 with multi split:

```
$content.split('"')[3].Split('/')[2]
```

Answer (score 0):

To complement [TessellatingHeckler's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49333525/45375) with solutions based only on  PowerShell's own `-split` and `-replace` operators:

```
PS> ('OUTPUT: "Id": "/Name/VALUE"' -split '/')[-1] -replace '"'
VALUE
```

Array index `-1` extracts the *last* element from the array of `/`-separated tokens that `-split '/'` outputs, and `-replace '"'` then removes any `"` instances from the result (in the absence of a replacement string, replaces them with the empty string, thereby effectively removing them).

---

With the help of a *regex* (regular expression), using `-replace` by itself is sufficient:

```
PS> 'OUTPUT: "Id": "/Name/VALUE"' -replace '.*/(.*?)"', '$1'
VALUE
```

- `.*/` greedily matches everything up to the *last* `/`
- `(.*?)"` non-greedily matches everything until a `"` is encountered; since `.*?` is enclosed in `(...)`, it is a so-called capture group that makes the sub-match available as `$1` in the replacement string.